# Testar as rotas em Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testes, phpunit

Caros,
pequise muito e não achei a solução para o que preciso.

Quero fazer um teste da minha aplicação, que no caso é um cadastro de Países.
A aplicação funciona perfeitamente.

O Controller chama as routes corretas, chamdas pelas comando corretos (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE):
- view   -> pais.view
- insert -> pais.insert
- store  -> pais.store
- edit   -> pais.edit
- update -> pais.update
- delete -> pais.delete

Criei a rotina de teste conforme abaixo:

```
   public function testHTML() : void {
        // inclusão normal
        $registro = [
            'codpais' => 1,
            'nompais' => 'Brasil',
            'sigpais' => 'BRA',
            '_token' => csrf_token()
        ];

    // chamo o evento post, com os dados
        $response = $this->call( 'POST', 'pais', $registro);
        $response->assertStatus(302);

    // pesquiso se o registro está no banco. 
    // Caso contrário quero retornar um erro
    // Até aqui aparentemente funcionou
        $pesq = Pais::find($registro['codpais']);
        if ($pesq->codpais != $registro['codpais']) {
            throw new Exception('Erro no cadastro de país.');;
        }

    // quero fazer um inclusão do mesmo registro
    // mas quero saber o erro que foi retornado
    // mas recebo o status = 302.
        $response = $this->call( 'POST', 'pais', $registro);
        print "\nPasso 2 ->" . $response->getStatusCode() . "\n";

    }
```

Queria testar se deu alguma mensagem de erro, que envio via session::flash, dentro do Controller.
Isso é possível?

Como vocês fazem este teste?
Vários exemplos que vejo tem que montar uma API, onde retorno o registro via json, mas eu quero testar a aplicação do usuário.

Será que estou querendo o impossível?

No aguardo
Tonico Bittencourt

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro estrutura o controller da seguinte forma, listagem, criar, deletar e alterar, ai depois com cada função no controller você já saberá que precisa de 2 funções a mais em cada que é visão de cadastro e visão de alterar, segue um exemplo de controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        //aqui vai ser ao abrir um post especifico.
    }

    public function lista() {

        $post = Post::with('autor')->get();

        return view('home', compact('post'));
    }

    public function cadastro() {

        return view('post.cadastrar');
    }

    public function cadastrar(Request $request) {

        $request->validate([
            'titulo' => 'required'
        ]);

        Post::create([
            'image' => $request->image,
            'titulo' => $request->titulo,
            'conteudo' => $request->conteudo
        ])->save($request->autor);

        return redirect()->back();

    }
}
```

Ai nas rotas você separa também como deve se comportar usando ou não o name isso é escolha sua, um exemplo de rotas:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'PostController@lista')->name('home');

Route::get('/post/criar', 'PostController@cadastro')->name('post.criar');
Route::get('/post/criado', 'PostController@cadastrar')->name('post.criado');
```

Ainda falta algumas rotas pra eu implementar é um projeto que estou fazendo para teste, mas espero ter te ajudado, qualquer dúvida só comentar...